# Underscore.js syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, underscore.js

I work with underscore.js templeting engine in html files (look at attached example).
My purpose is to make VS highlight js code in html file in addition to regular html highlighting.

```
<div>
<%
var isRelevant = hasInternetService;
var hasTestResults = _.has(bundle_results(), "internet_port") && bundle_results().internet_ppp.final_analysis != "failed";
var hasSync = _.has(bundle_results(), "internet_port") && bundle_results().internet_port.sync_status === "Up";
var iconSuffix = !isRelevant ? "down" : !hasTestResults ? "test-fail" : hasSync ? "up" : "down";
%>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you putting JS code in a `<div>`?

Comment: Because it's underscore.js templeting engine that allows me to write js logic in a html file.

Answer (score 3):

Those templates are called [ejs](https://ejs.co/), they are not supported in Visual Studio.

Here is a request for them [in the Microsoft uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752933-ejs-syntax-support).

So the answer to your question is "you can't".

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [EJS language support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support) (or similar) extension to  provide syntax highlighting and autocompletion for EJS (Embedded JavaScript) templates.